# Validating Bootstrap validator by jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to validate bootstrap when bootstrap is not valid on clicking on a button for example i have following button code

I have already applied CDN of bootstrap validator.

```
<form id="studentForm">
 <input type="text" name="name" required="">
  <button onclick="checkvalidation()" type="button">check</button>
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#studentForm').bootstrapValidator();
    });
```

i want to check in checkvalidation() form not on type submit how can I check

Comment: Have you tried `<form id="studentForm" onsubmit="checkvalidation()">`?

Comment: Onsubmit working but i want to send data through ajax neither on submit nor type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is handle the default action

So you i would suspect that you you woudl start of with something like this

```
$("button").on('click', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
}
```

The "event.preventDefault()" that simply stops the default propagation of what the basic method of that element and then you can apply your validation scripts and ajax method in that space.

if you have some detais on the plugin you are using that i can update my answer here, i have added a sample below for you to try out if you fancy.

```js
$("button").on('click', function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
 
  //check if input is null or blank
  if($("#name").val() == ""|| $("#name").val() == null){
    $("form").removeClass("needs-validation").addClass("was-validated");
  }
  else{
   alert("valid details")
  }
  
  //then you can do you ajax function here 
});
```

```css
form {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="icon" href="data:;base64,iVBORwOKGO=" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
      <label for="validationCustom01">First name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First name" value="" required>
      <div class="invalid-feedback">
        Please enter a name
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit form</button>
</form>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No this is not what am i looking for. I am looking for a code look like $('#form').validate() if validation is not complete then validation occur

Comment: So what's the plugin you are using, because i am confident that this will maintain a state of the form everytime you key in data, so you can use that do a check, pop the URl on here and i can amend my answer to fit what you need

Comment: I am using bootstrap validator and not type="submit" in button but I want to validate bootstrap validation. Is it possible

Comment: Sure thing what's the URL for the bootstrap validate library? The script tag src

Comment: Hi @SumitKumarGupta is this the repo you are talking about http://bootstrapvalidator.votintsev.ru/getting-started/. I would reccomend this one as it's in some of the templates from microsoft and is quite robust.

Comment: Why bootstrap validation is not working on type="button"